# Javascript/NodeJS forEach Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this forEach Loop:

```
 <% users.forEach(function(user) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= user.studio %></td>
     <td><%= user.name %></td>
     <td><%= user.email %></td>
     <td><%= user.username %></td>
     <td>
     <% user.comments.forEach(function(comment) { %>
         <%= comment.collected %>
     <% }); %>
     </td>
    <td ><a class="btn btn-primary" href="/users/<%= user._id %>">More Info</a></td>
<% }); %>
```

What I want to do is only show the users who have `'At Reception'` as the value of `comment.collected` but I am having problems figuring out how I would do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

The UserSchema in question looks like this:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    password: String,
    studio: {type: String, required: true},
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,

    comments: [
      {
            quantity: String,
            received: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            collected: { type: String, default: "At Reception" }
      }
   ],

    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

Comment: What is `user.comments`? An array?

Comment: Hi, yes, I've added the userSchema to the original post for clarification

Comment: Ok! You want to show users that have all their `comments.collected === 'At Reception'`? Or just at least one comment?

Comment: Preferably I would like to show every  `comments.collected === 'At Reception'` for a user. Essentially the list is showing parcels that are ready at reception and for who it is for etc but a user may have more than one  `comments.collected === 'At Reception'` if that makes sense?

Comment: I've added a note to my answer. Please check if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter the array first:

```
<% users.filter(function(user) {                            // filter only users
       return user.comments.some(function(comment) {        // that some (at least one) of their comments
           return comment.collected === "At Reception";     // have its collected property equal to "At Reception"
       });
   }).forEach(function(user) { %>
...
```

**NOTE:** The above code shows users that have at least has one comment whose `comment.collect === 'At Reception'`. If you want to show only users that have all their comments' collected property equal to `'At Reception'`, then use `Array#every` instead of `Array#some`:

```
...
return user.comments.every(...);
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Never even knew about filtering arrays, glad to have learnt something new